# Referencing Message UserProperties from SQLFilter

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azureservicebus

I'm trying to filter messages for my Subscription Clients in Azure Service Bus. I'd like to check if the property does not exist or the property has a certain value. This is how I add the filter:

```cs
var rules = await subscriptionClient_.GetRulesAsync();
if (!rules.Any(r => r.Name == "FilteringRule"))
{
    var filter = new SqlFilter($"sys.CustomProperty='{CustomValue}' OR sys.CustomProperty IS NULL");
    await subscriptionClient_.AddRuleAsync("FilteringRule", filter);
}
```

And the same value is passed over to the Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message object:

```cs
Message msg = new Message();
msg.UserProperties.Add("CustomProperty", "CustomValue");
```

Checking it in Service Bus explorer displays that the message indeed has the property.

I'm trying to figure out how to filter Subscriptions programmatically, not by ARM templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the filter is not working because you're trying to treat `custom properties` as `system properties`. Please try to change your filter expression to:

```cs
var filter = new SqlFilter($"CustomProperty='{CustomValue}' OR CustomProperty IS NULL");
```

and things should work. Please note that I have removed `sys.` prefix from your filter expression.

Comment: In the end I managed to figure it out as well. Thank you for you answer, it solves the problem!